# Got Tridion XPM Template Icons?

Tags: discussion

This isn't quite a regular TRex question, so I'm posting this to help **gather royalty-free, ready-to-use Component Template preview icons** in two sizes:

- 32 x 32
- 16 x 16

These are set in Templates:

[image: Component Templates have two preview icon sizes: 32x32 and 16x16]

They appear to CMS users in Experience Manager in the layout tab (I'm not actually recommending CTs to add blogging features, this is just an example):

[image: With a Component selected, XPM users can choose a different Component Template]

Source for the Blog Icon: [theblogicon.com](http://www.theblogicon.com/).

Here are the Tridion Reference Implementation **Component Templates** (as of October 2014):

- Accordion
- Accordion [2-Column]
- Accordion [3-Column]
- Article
- Carousel
- Carousel [Hero]
- Download
- List [2-Column]
- List [3-Column]
- Paged List
- Place
- Tab
- Teaser - Image Overlay [2-Column]
- Teaser - Image Overlay [3-Column]
- Teaser [2-Column]
- Teaser [3-Column]
- Teaser Colored [2-Column]
- Teaser Colored [3-Column]
- Teaser Hero - Image Overlay [Hero]
- Teaser Map [2-Column]
- Teaser Map [3-Column]
- Thumbnail List
- YouTube Video
- YouTube Video [2-Column]
- YouTube Video [3-Column]

And **Page Templates**:

- Content Page
- Content Page Without Navigation
- Home Page
- Redirect Page
- Section Page

### Post

Post answers with anything from your favorite "icon" (small image) sites to preferrably the actual images in the post or on your blog. You could re-use the same image across sizes or Templates if it makes sense (e.g. I didn't note the Schema relationships, so only certain Component Templates will appear based on a given Component).

*I won't stop you if you're inspired to explain the relationships between icons for multiple columns across different Component Templates.*

### Vote

Up to the community, but maybe **vote for the post you'll mostly likely come back to on your next Experience Manager setup** when you're thinking, "I need some good icons for these Templates."

*Maybe we could even get the icons into TRI, but I'll let you figure out if it's possible to convince "[Team TRI](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/reference_implementation.aspx)" and then how to add this to the installer.* :-)

Answer (score 2):

Royalty-free icons we mentioned on the Tridion Cookbook:

- [Ionicons](http://ionicons.com/)
- [Flat Icons Packs](http://www.flaticon.com/packs/)